# Removing a text from tinymce editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a text `<info>SOME CONTENTS GOES HERE</info>`

How i can remove this text from the editor when I click on a button (custom button) using javascript function. I used this code:

```
dom.remove(dom.getParent(selection.getNode(), 'info'));
```

But it is showing an error. Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = ed.selection.getNode();
var txt = ed.selection.getContent();
var newT = document.createTextNode(txt);
a.parentNode.replaceChild(newT, a);
```

Answer (score 11):

tinyMCE offers a method under DOMUtils which is [tinymce.dom.DOMUtils/remove](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aAPI/tinymce.dom.DOMUtils/remove)

```
// Removes all paragraphs in the active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.remove(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p'));

// Removes a element by id in the document
tinyMCE.DOM.remove('mydiv');
```

So in your case since you want to remove `<info>` and what's inside then you should write something like :

```
// Removes all paragraphs in the active editor
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.remove(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('info'));
```